# Are my variables categorical?

Tags: regression

If my variables all take on integer values between 0 and 10, where 0 represents dissatisfied and 10 is very satisfied, would this mean my variables are categorical?

Comment: Your variables are ordinal.

Comment: You don't say exactly how these variables were measured, but if it was something like "On a scale of 0 to 10, say how satisfied...." then your variables are ordinal and thus categorical in the wide sense. If your variables represented e.g. counts of separate items, then they could be called counted fractions and there might be some division of opinion on whether they are ordinal or counted. Either way, ordinal is the keyword to take forward.

Comment: @NickCox Yes that's how they are measured. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variables appear to be ordinal.

(thought someone should make this the answer, rather than leaving them as comments)